# How to restrict accessing a static pdf file by url in C#

Tags: c#

I am having an anchor tag which will open a pdf file in browser from my solution

```
<a href="~/MyFolder/MyStaticFile.pdf" target="_blank">MYFILE</a>
```

My problem is user is able to access this file even though he is not logged in by providing the url directly which he can get after login. Please help.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Or, using ASP.NET MVC, `return File(..);`

Comment: I agree with vesan, put some serverside code and check that they should have access to the file first.

Comment: Depending on the ASP.Net version, you may be able to just set RAMMFAR, that is `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` on the `modules` section in your `.config` file.

Comment: @Vesan: Thanks vesan... It worked.. :)